# add Number after the variable and echo it

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I want to echo the html inside The variables $p1 $p2 $p3 etc
So when i click the button next it goes to next page
when i click button previous it goes 1 page back.

This is my working code:

```
if ($pageShow == 0) {
    echo "<center>".$p1."</center>";
    } elseif ($pageShow == 1) {
    echo "<center>".$p1."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 2) {
    echo "<center>".$p2."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 3) {
    echo "<center>".$p3."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 4) {
    echo "<center>".$p4."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 5) {
    echo "<center>".$p5."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 6) {
    echo "<center>".$p6."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 7) {
    echo "<center>".$p7."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 8) {
    echo "<center>".$p8."</center>";
    }elseif ($pageShow == 9) {
    echo "<center>".$p9."</center>";
}
}
```

but i wanted to do it like this so it doesnt have that much lines of code:

echo '$p'.$_SESSION['hits'];

So when session is equal to 1 i tought the code would be echo $p1; and when Session is equal to 5 the code would do this echo $p5;

Comment: I still have no idea what you want to do

Comment: `echo '$p'.$_SESSION['hits'];` - use ' not "

Comment: Are you trying to write PHP in PHP?

Comment: I`m sorry for not being realy clear inexplaining. but my english is not realy good :(. And google translator is not an option ...

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes `'` for echoing a variable name. eg

```
echo '$p';
```

Then do what you did before:

```
echo '$p'.$_SESSION['hits'];
```

If `$_SESSION['hits']` is `5`, then it will read `$p5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "\$p".$_SESSION['hits'];
```

this returns as $p5

Comment: This is kinda what i need but. i wrote some html inside $p1 $p2 etc so when i click on a button The session gets added up 1 so it becomes 2 and then i want to display the html inside $p2   my other file: $p1 = <html> $p2 = <html><head></html></head>

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

By using the ", PHP is parsing the string and echoing the value of `$p`.  Instead use ' or escape the dollar sign.  Like:

```
echo '$p' . $_SESSION['hits'];
```

or

```
echo "\$p" . $_SESSION['hits'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understating that you are about to refer a dynamic variable try this

```
$sessionHits = 'p'.$_SESSION['hits'];
$finalOp     = $$sessionHits; // this will output if you have stored something in $p5 , as in this case $_SESSION['hits'] = 5
```